# I want to get the session name parameter by knowing its position c#

Tags: c#, session

If I cycle all the session vars with a `for` I'll know each position and value of the session var but I want to know the session var name.

```
for ( int i=0; i<Session.count; i++) {
Response.write(Session[i].ToString());
}
```

But I want to retrieve `Session` var by Name like

```
Response.write(Session["SessionVarName"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.keys.aspx) property of `Session`.

```
for ( int i=0; i < Session.Keys.Count; i++) {
    Response.write(Session.Keys[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of your session parameter by using `Session.Keys[Index]`, the value by index `Session[Index]` or value by parameter name `Session["Name"]`.

These are collection so you can loop over them to get all values and names.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string sVar in Session.Keys)
{
    // sVar contains the NAME of the key
}
```

or

```
for (i=0; i<Session.Count;i++)
    // Session.Keys[i] contains key name
```